# subplot to remove x y tick but to keep x y label

Tags: matlab, plot

I have following code:

```
linePair_max = 15;
nX = 40; nY = nX + 1;
nview = 80;
db = pi/nview;

x0 = linspace(-linePair_max, linePair_max, nX);
y0 = linspace(-linePair_max, linePair_max, nY);

[x,y] = meshgrid(x0, y0);
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(x,y,'b*');   axis image
FontSize = 20;
title('fully sampled k-space', 'FontSize',FontSize )
xlabel('k_x','FontSize',FontSize )
ylabel('k_y','FontSize',FontSize )
lgd = legend('sampling');
lgd.FontSize = FontSize;
%set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0])

M = 2;
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(x(1:M:nY,:),y(1:M:nY,:),'b*'); axis image
title('decimated k-space', 'FontSize',FontSize )
xlabel('k_x','FontSize',FontSize )
ylabel('k_y','FontSize',FontSize )
lgd = legend('sampling');
lgd.FontSize = FontSize;
```

which generate following figure:
[image]
I am wondering can I remove ticks on x, y axis, but keep the label (remove those numbers but keep kx and ky)? Many say

```
set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0])
```

but I did not have the luck to get it working. Thanks alot.

Comment: do you mean to remove the line and keep the numbers? Or to remove the numbers and keep the kx ky?

Comment: remove the number but keep kx and ky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xticklabels(''); yticklabels('');
```